Comparison of `str` references in match results in compiliation error
I have the following (simplified) function to check a url::Host for localhost
fn is_localhost(host: &Host<&str>) -> bool {
    match host {
        Host::Domain(d) => {
            d == "localhost" || d.ends_with(".localhost")
        },
        Host::Ipv4(a) => a.is_loopback(),
        Host::Ipv6(a) => a.is_loopback(),
    }
}

Doing a cargo check show's me the following error message
d == "localhost" || d.ends_with(".localhost")
  ^^ no implementation for `&str == str`

The solution is to dereference d in the comparison: *d == "localhost". Which struck me as weird, but I could explain it to myself at that time... somehow. However, later (in another function) I have the following code:
if url.scheme() == "https" {
    return true;
}

Note that url.scheme() returns a &str. I now that the expression "https" is a &'static str just like in the match further above.
Why does this work here and not in the match?

To resolve the compilation error in the is_localhost function, you need to adjust how you handle references in the match expression. The simplest fix is to dereference the host parameter in the match statement by using match *host instead of match host. This removes one level of reference, allowing d to be a &str instead of &&str. The comparison d == "localhost" will work without further modifications. This maintains the function's logic while correctly handling the reference levels involved in matching against a &Host<&str> parameter

Why is d a &&str in the match and not simply a &str like the docs on url::Host say it is? I am just matching against the plain value inside the Host::Domain enum.

I updated my response.

@jtepe Because of "match ergonomics." When you match a reference to an enum, you should need to match on e.g. &Host::Domain(_), but Rust lets you instead match on Host::Domain(_), which implicitly causes the bound values extracted from the enum to also be references. It's as though you had written &Host::Domain(ref d).

@cdhowie Yeah, that makes sense. Those ergonomics came in with 1.26 IIRC. Thanks. That makes it clear.

I guess, what I have been confused about is that Rust seems to automatically dereference both by one level, i.e. the message no implementation for &str == str. I would have been more helpful to see it as no implementation for &&str == &str.
